# Given a sequence {bn}, with two subsequence which both converge, proof that {bn} not have to be convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Given a sequence $\{bn\}$, with two subsequences which both converge, prove that $b_n$ need to  converge.

Given $bn$ and subsequences $b_{2n}$ and $b_{2n+1},$
where $b_{2n}$ and $b_{2n+1}$ are both covergent,
Show that $bn$ dosen´t have to be convergent.

I know that if $bn$ is covergent then all of the subsequences of it must have the same limit point let´s say $x$.
But if $b_{2n}$ has limit point $y$ and $b_{2n+1}$ has limit point $z$ then $b_n$ cannot be convergent, but how can i  show that??

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to prove anything because you have the proposition which states that if a sequence has a limit say $x$ then every subsequence must converge to $x$.

The convergence of the subsequences to the same limit is a necessary condition.

If exist  subsequences of $x_n$ which converge to different limits then $x_n$ cannot be convergent

Let  $k$ a non negative integer.

Then all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ can be written: $$n=ks+m$$ where $o \leq m \leq k$(think of this as the euclideian division where a  natural number depends on the remainder $m$).

For instance if you take the number $5$ then each natural number $n$ can be expressed in the form $n=5s+m$  for some $s \in \mathbb{N}$ and $0 \leq m \leq 4$

You can do this for every number $k$ in other words you can partition the set of natural numbers to $k$ disjoint sets.Take for instance $k=10$ and think it your self what are all the possible forms the natural numbers will have.

Now why do i mention this?

If you take a sequence $x_n$ and you prove for instance that the subsequences $x_{3n+1},x_{3n+2},x_{3n}$ (where you chose $k=3$) converge to the same limit $l$ then $x_n$ converges to $l$ .

You can do this for every $k$(partition)

Your case is when $k=2$ where we partition the set of natural numbers to two disjointsets, the sets of odd numbers and the set of event numbers.

According to your question if you prove that $x_{2n},x_{6n},x_{3n}$ converge to the same limit then you don't prove that $x_n$ has the same limit.

I hope this helps.

Comment: But what if there were three subsequences, which are convergent {b2n}, {b2n+1},{b3n+1}??

Comment: Then you have another proposition where: if $x_{2n},x_{2n+1}$ converge to the same limit $l$  then $x_n$ also converges to $l$..You can  prove it an an exercise and you don't need  $x_{3n+1}$..

Comment: If you want to prove that a sequence does or does not converge then one way is to examine the sequences $x_{2n}$ and $x_{2n+1}$

Comment: What if i used that {b_{6n}} is a subsequence of both {b_{2n}} and {b_{3n}} then they would have the same limit point, and {b_{9}} for {b_{3n}} and {b_{2n+1}}

Comment: Ok @Zimo i will edit my answer to show you something.

Answer (score 1):

Take $b_n=(-1)^n$.

$\{b_{2n}\}$ converges and $\{b_{2n-1}\}$ converges, but $\{b_n\}$ does not.

Let $A=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow+\infty}b_n$ and $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}.$

Thus, for all $N>0$ there is $n>N$ for which $|b_n-A|\geq\epsilon$.

Comment: But can you show that in generel?? I am thinking like a proof

Comment: @Zimo I added something.